# How to get user's local sytem's datetime in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the date and time of user's local system.

How can I accomplish that in a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you need to capture it via JavaScript and then send it back to the server (eg. using AJAX).

In the JavaScript: `var d = new Date()` will capture what you need.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried this approach too and to set the time with javascript and get it in server side, I used cookies and setTimeInterval method. This normally works fine but in case of ajax forms I dont know why it sends old time with cookies. Can you help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This was my solution:

Note: Requires jQuery.

In the Head of the _Layout file (or all _Layout files if there are multiple), after the jQuery declarations, put:

```
@if (Session["UTCOffset"] == null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.post('/Home/SetUTC', { UTC: new Date().getTimezoneOffset() }, function (data) { location.reload(); });
        </script>
    }
```

In the Home controller (or whatever controller you use), put:

```
public JsonResult SetUTC(int UTC)
        {
            Session["UTCOffset"] = (-1*UTC).ToString();
            return Json(null);
        }
```

When printing out date times, use (in this example DateTime.Now):

```
(DateTime.Now).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(double.Parse((string)Session["UTCOffset"]??"-300.00")).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

-300 is central time (my time zone). If there are any dates on the very first page they hit, they will be displayed in central time. For about a second. Then the page will be reloaded and things should work as expected.

I'm sure this could be somehow adapted for non-MVC setups but I'll leave that for somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

There's **no way you can do that in server-side asp.net mvc** code.

Either you **prompt the user with DtropDown list of all timezones and let him pick it from the list** and second option is to **capture local system time in client-javascript and send it to server over an AJAX request** or a post-back.

In fact there's one more way - You can **capture the IP of the user's machine and find out the country to which that IP belongs to** and pick the TimeZone of that country. You can use MaxMind GeoIP database which can help you do this very easily.

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach too and to set the time with javascript and get it in server side, I used cookies and setTimeInterval method. This normally works fine but in case of ajax forms I dont know why it sends old time with cookies. Can you help with this? Thanks.

Comment: @gaurav - Why are you sending the time in cookies?  Why not just grab it once and then keep track of it for that user or session?

Comment: Got it, Thanks you all for giving your valuable time. :)